# Basic gravity implementation in OpenGL

Tags: c++, game-physics

I'm trying to implement jumping in my OpenGL game. My left and right 'velocity' and 'friction' is working well, but I'm not able to get my jump working in a nice arc. The player gets stuck in the air:

```
void keyboard() {
    //Move Left
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(keyA)) {
        playerVelX -= 3;
    }
    //Move Right
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(keyD)) {
        playerVelX += 3;
    }
    //Jump
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(keySpace)) {
        playerVelY += 3;
    }
}

void position() {
    //Move on x and y axis
    playerX += playerVelX;
    playerY += playerVelY;

    //Slow down respective axes
    playerVelX *= friction;
    playerVelY *= gravity;
}

while(gameRunning) {
    keyboard();
    position();
}
```

I think I've been looking at it too long. Does anyone have experience implementing gravity like this? Thanks

Comment: Just `-=` in gravity will do the job. You can say that `vel -= gravity;` and then `pos += vel;`. And also make sure that your keyboard event for the jump breaks after pressing the key once. Otherwise, it will keep incrementing the jump by `+=3`.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula for applying gravity is wrong. Remember that `F=m.a`, `v=v_0+ a*t`, `x=x_0 +v_0*t + 0.5*a*t^2`. But the usual approach is to use Euler's method for numerical integration:

```
gravity=9.81;
velocity+=gravity*deltaT;
position+=velocity*deltaT;
```

In your code it would look like:

```
playerVelX *= friction;
playerVelY -= gravity;//If Y point up, so gravity acts against that.

playerX += playerVelX;
playerY += playerVelY;
```

If you want to have deterministic and stable simulation (which you should) then you need to have `deltaTime` - how much time passed since last update. See this excellent article [Fix Your Timstep!](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) . Also the code above applies the gravity constantly,even when not jumping, so be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing all inaccuracies:

1. Obvious mistake `m * dv/dt = -m * g` so `dv = -g * dt` so  `playerVelY -= gravity * dt`
2. In the jump, further repulsion is impossible, so

   ```
   if (GetAsyncKeyState(keySpace) && (playerY <= groundLevel)) {
       playerVelY += 3;
   }
   ```
3. Gravity should not act if the player is on the surface.

   ```
   if (playerY < groundLevel)
   {
      playerY = groundLevel;
      playerVelY = 0; 
   }
   ```

   More realistic to take into account the reaction force.
4. Your model `playerVelX *= friction`; corresponds to viscous friction. The player will never stop. Are you sure you need viscous, not dry friction?
5. `dt` should be defined as real time between updates otherwise, the result will depend on the current refresh rate. You need something like

   ```
   void position() {
      static double lastTime = getCurrTime();
      double currTime = getCurrTime();
      double dt = currTime - lastTime;

      playerX += playerVelX * dt;
      playerY += playerVelY * dt;

      if (playerY < groundLevel)
      {
          playerY = groundLevel;
          playerVelY = 0; 
      }

      //Slow down respective axes
      playerVelX *= exp(-friction * dt); // playerVelX *= (1 - friction * dt) for small dt
      playerVelY -= gravity * dt;

      lastTime = currTime;
   }
   ```